# Set property in parent control with a trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a window with a couple of buttons. The buttons opens different others windows. When one of this window is open, I want to set the effect property of the parent window. Is that completely possible within the xaml code? Maybe with a template, style or trigger?

Sorry for the late response. Here is the xaml of the window. I simplified the header and of course i know that this code doesn't work. But that was my idea to get a solution.

```
    <Window>
        <Window.Style><Window.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Window">
                <Setter Property="Effect">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <BlurEffect Radius="0"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" Value="True">                    
                        <Setter Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <BlurEffect Radius="6"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Window.Style>

<Stackpanel>
<Button Name="B1"/>
<Button Name="B2"/>
<Button Name="B3>"/>
</StackPanel>

        </Window>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that the users can help you solve your problem

Comment: You can't do that in pure XAML, but you can do it. The parent window can pass a command to the child window, which can bind it to a button. When the button is clicked, the command will execute. The command the parent window passes to the child window can do anything the parent window wants it to, including setting the parent window's `Effect` property. I can't tell you how exactly to adapt that solution to your code, because I have no idea what your code looks like.